# Why does apple disallow certain crypto apps on their app store? And how does one pass this verification?

Tags: ios, mac, appstore

I created an app for an NXT/Ardor cryptocurrency and tried to submit this to the apple app store, but got denied. After doing some research I came across this post stating there is an "approved" list of coins they support.

https://www.ios-blog.co.uk/resources/apples-approved-list-of-virtual-currencies/#official-list

How does one get on this approved list? What does one need to do to get on this approved list? The core devs of this platform is willing to help get on this list.